# Don´t show empty days in business hours template from JReviews FormBuilder

Tags: php, formbuilder

Good morning, we use Joomla and JReviews and in some listings we show the opening hours. That works fine with the business hours template. Now we want to change this template for some other listings with training times.

We want, that for example the training is just on tuesdays all other days will display none.

The Code is like this:

```
{
"title": "Periods",
"type": "array",
"format": "table",
"items": {
    "title": "Kurszeit",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "day": {
            "title": "Tag",
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "#\/definitions\/weekeday",
            "options": {
                "input_width": "15em"
            }
        },
        "hours-start": {
            "title": "Von",
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "#\/definitions\/hours",
            "options": {
                "input_width": "15em"
            }
        },
        "hours-end": {
            "title": "Bis",
            "type": "string",
            "$ref": "#\/definitions\/hours",
            "options": {
                "input_width": "15em"
            }
        }
    }
},
"definitions": {
    "weekeday": {
        "type": "string",
        "enumSource": [
            {
                "source": [
                    {
                        "value": "1",
                        "title": "Montag"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "2",
                        "title": "Dienstag"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "3",
                        "title": "Mittwoch"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "4",
                        "title": "Donnerstag"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "5",
                        "title": "Freitag"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "6",
                        "title": "Samstag"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "7",
                        "title": "Sonntag"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "{{item.title}}",
                "value": "{{item.value}}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "hours": {
        "type": "string",
        "enumSource": [
            {
                "source": [
                    {
                        "value": "5.0",
                        "title": "05:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "5.25",
                        "title": "05:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "5.5",
                        "title": "05:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "5.75",
                        "title": "05:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "6.0",
                        "title": "06:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "6.25",
                        "title": "06:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "6.5",
                        "title": "06:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "6.75",
                        "title": "06:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "7.0",
                        "title": "07:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "7.25",
                        "title": "07:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "7.5",
                        "title": "07:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "7.75",
                        "title": "07:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "8.0",
                        "title": "08:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "8.25",
                        "title": "08:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "8.5",
                        "title": "08:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "8.75",
                        "title": "08:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "9.0",
                        "title": "09:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "9.25",
                        "title": "09:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "9.5",
                        "title": "09:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "9.75",
                        "title": "09:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "10.0",
                        "title": "10:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "10.25",
                        "title": "10:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "10.5",
                        "title": "10:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "10.75",
                        "title": "10:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "11.0",
                        "title": "11:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "11.25",
                        "title": "11:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "11.5",
                        "title": "11:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "11.75",
                        "title": "11:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "12.0",
                        "title": "12:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "12.25",
                        "title": "12:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "12.5",
                        "title": "12:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "12.75",
                        "title": "12:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "13.0",
                        "title": "13:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "13.25",
                        "title": "13:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "13.5",
                        "title": "13:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "13.75",
                        "title": "13:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "14.0",
                        "title": "14:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "14.25",
                        "title": "14:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "14.5",
                        "title": "14:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "14.75",
                        "title": "14:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "15.0",
                        "title": "15:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "15.25",
                        "title": "15:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "15.5",
                        "title": "15:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "15.75",
                        "title": "15:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "16.0",
                        "title": "16:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "16.25",
                        "title": "16:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "16.5",
                        "title": "16:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "16.75",
                        "title": "16:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "17.0",
                        "title": "17:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "17.25",
                        "title": "17:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "17.5",
                        "title": "17:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "17.75",
                        "title": "17:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "18.0",
                        "title": "18:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "18.25",
                        "title": "18:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "18.5",
                        "title": "18:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "18.75",
                        "title": "18:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "19.0",
                        "title": "19:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "19.25",
                        "title": "19:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "19.5",
                        "title": "19:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "19.75",
                        "title": "19:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "20.0",
                        "title": "20:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "20.25",
                        "title": "20:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "20.5",
                        "title": "20:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "20.75",
                        "title": "20:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "21.0",
                        "title": "21:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "21.25",
                        "title": "21:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "21.5",
                        "title": "21:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "21.75",
                        "title": "21:45 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "22.0",
                        "title": "22:00 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "22.25",
                        "title": "22:15 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "22.5",
                        "title": "22:30 Uhr"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "22.75",
                        "title": "22:45 Uhr"
                    }
                ],
                "title": "{{item.title}}",
                "value": "{{item.value}}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Code for output is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     JReviews
 * @author      ClickFWD LLC (https://www.jreviews.com)
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2010-2018 ClickFWD LLC
 * @license     GNU GPL version 3 or later
 */

defined('MVC_FRAMEWORK') or die;


$twentyfourHourFormat = true;

$daysArray = [
    1 => __l('Montag',true),
    2 => __l('Dienstag',true),
    3 => __l('Mittwoch',true),
    4 => __l('Donnerstag',true),
    5 => __l('Freitag',true),
    6 => __l('Samstag',true),
    7 => __l('Sonntag',true)
    ];

$data = json_decode($text, true);

if ( (isset($data['periods']) && empty($data['periods'])) || empty($data) ) return;

$periods = isset($data['periods']) ? $data['periods'] : $data;

$timezone = isset($data['timezone']) ? $data['timezone'] : null;

S2App::import('Helper', 'opening_hours', 'jreviews');

$OpeningHours = (new OpeningHours($timezone))->addPeriods($periods);

$days = $OpeningHours
            ->twentyfour($twentyfourHourFormat)
            ->getOrderedPeriods();

$openNowLabel = __t("Open now", true);
$closedNowLabel = __t("Closed now", true);
$closedLabel = __t("Closed", true);
?>

<?php echo $this->renderControllerView('fields_phpformat', 'business_hours_schedule', compact('OpeningHours','days','daysArray'));?>
```

At the moment the Output is like this:
Monday:
Tuesday: 10:00 - 11:00
Wednesday:
Thursday:
Friday:
Saturday:
Sunday:

But we want this:
Tuesday: 10:00 - 11:00

Hopefully we could explain what we want.
Hopefully we could explain what we want.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user or developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.